# Heroku won't recognize 'pg' gem in my Rails app Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm still a relative newbie to Ruby on Rails, and I'm a complete newbie with Heroku.

I've set up my Rails app to use postgres instead of sqlite3, both in development and in production, and I've put "gem 'pg'" in my Gemfile.  And locally, my app is working just fine.

Making it work on Heroku is a different story.  After I've pushed my app to Heroku, when I type in "heroku run rake db:migrate", it tells me, "rake aborted!  Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile."

Yes, `gem 'pg'` is in my Gemfile, but I'm still getting this error.

What gives?

Here's what my Gemfile looks like right now:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails',        '4.0.1'
gem 'pg'

group :assets do
end

gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'
gem 'haml'
gem 'devise', '3.0.0.rc'
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'
gem 'knockout-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'unicorn'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Here's what my database.yml is like:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: financemeter
  pool: 5
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: financemeter
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: dbe67fgdnnqg88
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  user: njatxlpjjrzfoe
  password: HULxOtPALAk4FnzZe-_737TvPc
```

And here are the full error logs when I try to migrate on heroku. (Again, locally I'm fine.   I'm working locally on a MacBook if that matters.)

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:58:in `rescue in resolve_hash_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:55:in `resolve_hash_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:46:in `resolve_string_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:32:in `spec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:39:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:176:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:174:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:250:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
```

Comment: Make sure to do a bundle install and commit your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock after it. Try deploying then

Comment: I tried that - it didn't help.  I do have to wonder if it's because Heroku isn't getting updated - when I do "git push heroku master," it returns back a simple "Everything up-to-date" message without telling me my changes have been pushed.

Comment: You do realise you have the 'pg' gem twice in your gemfile? Try removing it from the `:production` group then run `bundle update`, `bundle install` and try to push that.

Comment: Oops, thanks for pointing it out.  I took out that line from the :production group and I've corrected my post to reflect that.  Unfortunately, it didn't work and I'm still having this problem. :(

Comment: Are you using git branches? Maybe you messed up something with git. Try `git push -f heroku master` to force a push into remote HEAD.

Comment: Thanks - that still didn't help.  :(

Answer (score 1):

Do you have postgresql installed on your machine? 
If not, use homebrew to install pg.
Once installed, make sure you initialize the pg datastore.

also, depending how your pg is installed, you might need to specify the username and host in your database.yml file

```
  username: someuser_on_pg
  host: localhost
```

Hope that helps

Comment: @drumwolf did you add an instance of the Heroku Postgres server on your heroku dashboard account or command line?


  heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql

Comment: I think I might have.  I ultimately ended up creating an entirely new Rails app from scratch with the "--database=postgresql" command, and then migrating all of my assets,controllers,models,views, etc. from my old app to the new app, and finally merging them in github.  Very inelegant, but it worked.